# Why does the Search icon look weird on small screen widths?

Tags: bug, design, search, top-bar

On a small screen width, the search icon looks like this:

[image]

In my opinion, the search button should look like all the other icons and not stand out as if it is 3D. I don't recall seeing this before, so I presume it is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). I could only reproduce this on small screen widths (tested in Firefox on Windows 11 and on Microsoft Edge on a mobile device).

Can the Search icon be made to look not 3d, so it is consistent with all the other icons in that navbar?